# emacs quail input method - how to complete a key sequence

Tags: emacs

I'm using a specialized input method (from M-x set-input-method), and quail is showing me the completion of a key sequence on the minibuffer. There happens to be only one single way to complete the sequence. Is there a way to tell emacs/quail to auto-complete at this point?